# Does Hamas have any particular/concrete demands stated on the conditions of which they intend to release the hostages?

Tags: hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

It’s all very well known that Hamas have taken many hostages from their attack in October. But are there any specific demands that they have stated will result in the hostages’ release? Or are they just being kept for nebulous “leverage”?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hamas leader Yahya Sinwar have offered to exchange the people it
has imprisoned for all Palestinians Israel has imprisoned:

> “We are ready to conduct an immediate prisoner exchange deal that
> includes the release of all Palestinian prisoners from Israeli jails
> in exchange for all prisoners held by the Palestinian resistance,”
> Yahya Sinwar, Hamas’s leader in the Gaza Strip, said in a statement.

> https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/10/28/prisoner-exchange-israeli-captive-families-demand-answers-from-netanyahu

According to recent unconfirmed news, Israel and Hamas has
agreed on an exchange. Hamas will release 100 prisoners in exchange
for all Palestinian women and children held by Israel:

> More than a month after the Palestinian group launched the “Al Aqsa
> Flood Operation” operation, Hamas and Israel have reached an
> agreement on a prisoner swap arrangement while Israel persisted in
> its attacks on the beleaguered Gaza Strip.

> Arab media quoted sources as saying that the two sides had agreed to
> exchange 100 detainees held by Hamas for the release of Palestinian
> women and children detained by Israel.

> https://www.samaa.tv/208734239-hamas-israel-reach-prisoner-swap-agreement

[According to
Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_prisoners_in_Israel)
there were 4,450 Palestinian security prisoners in Israeli prisons in
2022 of whom 160 were children and 32 women. In previous prisoner
exchanges with Israel, Hamas has been able to free hundreds of
Palestinian prisoners for every freed Israeli, so relatively fewer
would be freed this time.

Comment: Israel denied the latter https://www.agenzianova.com/en/news/netanyahu-israele-manterra-il-controllo-su-gaza-nessuna-intesa-per-uno-scambio-di-prigionieri-con-hamas/ "Meanwhile, there is still no agreement on the exchange of prisoners and the release of the Israeli hostages held by Hamas, reported the Israeli broadcaster "Kan", denying what was previously announced by the Saudi channel "Al Arabiya", which had spoken of an agreement to release 100 women and minors detained by Hamas."